# Vim: Replace regular expression match on a line with another regular expression match from same line

Tags: regex, vim

Hi:  I'm trying to 'pivot' some values in vim using search/replace, but seem to be stuck.

Consider the following file:

```
key1: value1, value2, value3, ... valueN\n
key2: valueA, valueB, valueC,...valueX\n
...
```

I'm trying to convert every ',' with the 'key' on that line, followed by a newline.

So, the output would be:

```
value1:key1\n
value2:key1\n
value3:key1\n
...
valueN:key1\n
valueA:key2\n
valueB:key2\n
...
```

I'm not sure how to replace every occurrence of a regex match (',' in this case) with the first match.

I tried:

```
:%s/\(^.\{-}\): \(.\{-}\),/\2:\1\r
```

but this only replaces the first occurrence of ','.

How do I replace EVERY occurrence of ',' with \1 for EACH line?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to do too many things at once, but it can be done with Vim if you insist:

```
:%s/\v\s*(\w+):\s*(.*)/\=substitute(submatch(2), '\v\s*%(,\s*|$)', ':' . submatch(1) . '\n', 'g')/
```

Input:

```
key1: value1, value2, value3
key2: valueA, valueB, valueC
```

Output:

```
value1:key1
value2:key1
value3:key1

valueA:key2
valueB:key2
valueC:key2
```

Comment: Thank you!  Will dig into the substitute and submatch functions.  Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it is possible with macros or vimscript, but if `perl` solution is okay for you...

```
$ cat ip.txt 
key1: value1, value2, value3, valueN
key2: valueA, valueB, valueC, valueX

$ perl -pe 's/^([^:]+):\s*(.*)/$2/; $k=$1; s/(value\w+),?\s*/$1:$k\n/g' ip.txt 
value1:key1
value2:key1
value3:key1
valueN:key1
valueA:key2
valueB:key2
valueC:key2
valueX:key2
```

If the output is as expected, change `perl -pe` to `perl -i -pe` for inplace editing

Comment: Thanks.  I can get this done using a 'language' (perl/python...), but was hoping to do it in vim, interactively...

Comment: @AaCc, so the answer by Sato should do :)